# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: javascript, angular

Hola amigos estoy tratando de desarrollar una aplicacion y llegue a un punto donde la propiedad subscribe del metodo onSubmit no me funciona y me dice que no existe en el tipo void alguna idea de que puede ser?

```
onSubmit() {
    this._userService.updateUser(this.user).subscribe(
        response => {
            if(!response.user){
                this.status = 'error';
                //console.log(response);
            }else{
                this.status = 'success';
                localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.user));
                this.identity = this.user;

                if(this.filesToUpload != null){
                    this._uploadService.makeFileRequest(this.url+'upload-image-user/'+this.user._id, [], this.filesToUpload, this.token, 'image').then((result: any) => {
                        //console.log(result);
                        this.user.image = result.user.image;
                        localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.user));
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        error => {
            var errorMessage = <any>error;
            console.log(errorMessage);
            if(errorMessage != null){
                this.status = 'error';
            }
        }
        );
}
```

---

listo! no me estaba guardando los cambios del updateUser guarde manualmente y quedo funcionando! gracias a todos!

Comment: Agrega el código de `updateUser() `

Comment: Tal cual... el error parece estar en la funcion `updateUser()`

Comment: Viendo únicamente el error, creo que el método `updateUser` no devuelve ningun valor, pero deberia devolver un observable

Comment: listo! no me estaba guardando los cambios del updateUser guarde manualmente y quedo funcionando! gracias a todos!

Comment: Si lograste solucionar el problema, agrega una respuesta con la solución así otras personas pueden hacer uso de tu respuesta.